# [Open Telemetry][otel-collector][prometheus] There's a huge delay between the sending of metrics and their processing

Tags: prometheus, open-telemetry

I'm currently mounting an Open Telemetry - Prometheus stack to be able to process metrics, as a POC for now.

I'm sending continuous data to the Otel-collector, which then export it as Prometheus endpoint, which in turns gets scraped by a Prometheus server.

The problem is that it takes forever for a new metric to appear in Prometheus. I spent the evening yelling at my computer yesterday, only to find out that the metric appeared this morning by magic. I'm trying the same installation on a different server and I have the same result, no metrics yet after an hour.

What am I doing wrong ? I tried enabling debug logging on otel-collector, I keep seeing that the metric get "accumulated" by the exporter, but it's not available to be scraped.

Here's my configuration:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml
    ports:
      - 1888:1888 # pprof extension
      - 8888:8888 # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
      - 8889:8889 # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - 13133:13133 # health_check extension
      - 4317:4317 # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - 4318:4318 # OTLP http receiver
      - 55679:55679 # zpages extension
    networks:
      - classroom-management_webnet

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - classroom-management_webnet
    volumes: 
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
    command: --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --log.level=debug

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3131:3131
    environment: 
      - GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT=3131
    networks:
      - classroom-management_webnet

networks:
  classroom-management_webnet:
    external: true
```

otel-collector-config.yml

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
      grpc:

exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8889
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: []
      exporters: [logging,prometheus]
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
```

prometheus.yml

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'otel-collector'
  scrape_interval: 1s
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['otel-collector:8888']
```

I tried changing the otel-collector processor from batch to none to memory_limiter, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your prometheus configuration, you are scraping the otel-collector's `8888` port which is where the collector emits its own metrics. Because you are using the prometheus exporter from the collector, you'll want to also scrape the prometheus exporter port (`8889`).